# Will TensorFlow2.0 trim unncessary computations?

Tags: tensorflow

Will TensorFlow 2.0 be able to trim unnecessary computations?

For example,

```
a = tf.constant(1.0)
for i in range(10):
  c = a + 1
  a = a + 1
print(a)
```

In TF1.x, `c=a+1` won't be computed. Will TF2.0 automatically detect `c=a+1` is not used so it doesn't do the computation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be computed. The preprocessor will detect it is never used and the program won't take into account. You can (not recommended) suppress warnings about unused stuff, instead, you should take care of the unused things.

Comment: I don't understand. Tensorflow 2.0 uses eager evaluation so by definition it evaluates the value line by line. How does TF avoid this computation in eager mode?

Comment: @KLX this is a preprocessor step, once the evaluation is done and it is aware of unused objects, it will not take them into account when actually processing.

You can see it this way, it is like when you compile a program in C, the same evaluation will be done, but since it was detected unused, it won't be finally computed. This gives you the chance to clean up your code, even though the actual operations won't be computed. This is easy to prove with a memory map once the program was executed.